# Chrome does not start on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: google-chrome

After reinstallation of GPU drivers, my Chrome stopped working.

During starting in terminal, I got errors:

```
[16557:16557:0608/010727.897828:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to
call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path=
/org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported:
This method is not implemented
[16557:16587:0608/010737.186513:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)]
Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
```

Comment: It seems to be looking for a screensaver, registered according to the Free Desktop Standard. Are you trying to run `chrome` in a non-GUI environment? That won't work.